# What frameworks built upon Open XML SDK are there?

Tags: .net, excel, ms-word, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

Since the Open XML SDK only provides strongly typed classes it does not really take pain of creating and manipulating Open XML documents. Are there any frameworks built upon the Open XML SDK that do what a framework is supposed to do: adding a new layer of abstraction and actually hiding the details of the lower layers?

So far I know one library but I'm wondering if there are some more:

- [ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (A library for easily creating Excel documents without dealing with the hassles of XML Documents)

Comment: If less, but still some, control is what you're looking for, how about the Interop approach? I'd say that OpenXml is for those of us who need crazy-fine control.

Comment: Do you mean the Interop assemblies for automating Office? The problem with that is that it is not really working properly on a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Open XML SDK is already a layer of abstraction over the existing `System.IO.Packaging` API, which was how you used to create and manipulate Open XML documents by accessing and writing the actual XML.  Now the Open XML SDK is a ton better than the old way, but it still requires a good amount of knowledge of the underlying XML in order to use this SDK.

With all of that said there is one built on the `System.IO.Packaging` API for Excel documents called [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) that provides the layer of abstraction you are looking for with easier to construct classes and methods to make an actual Excel 2007 spreadsheet.

I don't tend to look for many frameworks since the customized Open XML SDK code I need to write I normally can't get from a third party framework.